# Lightbox opens only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, jwplayer

i've a lighbox problem.

i use a jw player callback function onFullscreen to open a lightbox (jquery) this works, but only one time. if i close the lightbox i can't open it again.

in the lightbox overlay is another player with the same video but a different dimension.

you can try it and see the code here: http://rbb-rbb.lutzschramm.eu/rbb_breit/_02_uebersicht_demo_lightbox_fsbtn2.html

press the fullscreen-button (lower right corner) to open the lightbox.

thanks for taking time

marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overlay is only created once, the first time it will be opened because of you set the load-option to true(this means, the overlay opens when it was created). On further clicks no overlay will be created(it already exist and is hidden).

What to do :
add this line at the end of openLB():

```
$("#LBPlayer").data('overlay').load();
```

It will load(show) the overlay on further clicks.